# Soma de valores de arquivo xml

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho a necessidade de fazer uma soma de valores de um arquivo xml. Como pouco ja trabalhei com Curl extraindo dados de outro arquivo ou pagina, não sei nem como começar.
o layout do arquivo seria este.

```
0|0|0|0|3|0|0|46.000|
```

O valor a ser somando seria o 46.000 + os valores das próximas linhas. Mais deveria ser considerado somente as linha que tivesse o valor 3.

Alguém tem algum código do tipo? Já pesquisei e não achei nada relacionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar `preg_match_all` para encontrar todas as linhas que se encaixem em um determinado padrão (inclusive o caractere `3` na quinta posição), e depois somar todos os valores encontrados na oitava posição de cada linha:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|3\|\d+\|\d+\|(\d+\.\d+)\|/', 
$valores, $encontrados);
$total = 0;
foreach ($encontrados[1] as $encontrado) {
    $total += floatval($encontrado);
}
```

Caso você não saiba: o primeiro argumento de `preg_match_all` é uma expressão regular, e seu propósito é o de encontrar todas as ocorrências em um texto que se encaixem nessa expressão – no caso, o formato do dado que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar, mais tarde irei testar.

Comment: Tentei assim `<?php
$valores = file_get_contents('tce.txt');
preg_match_all('/\b\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|3\|\d+\|\d+\|([\d\.]+)\b/', $valores, $encontrados);
$total = 0;
foreach ($encontrados as $encontrado) {
   print $total += $encontrado[7];
}
?>`

Comment: Mais não consegui.

Comment: Complemente a pergunta com um trecho do arquivo contendo os dados, para ajudar na resolução do problema.

Comment: `12356|743|4584|1|3|03|2016|127.000|
12356|747|9176|1|3|03|2016|1123.511|
12356|748|7559|1|3|03|2016|776.799|
12356|749|1467|1|3|03|2016|601.017|` Cada começo 12356| e uma linha e assim por diante.

Comment: mudei a expressão regular e o código PHP, tente agora.

Comment: Usei da seguinte forma `$valores = file_get_contents('tce.txt');
preg_match_all('/\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|3\|\d+\|\d+\|(\d+\.\d+)\|/', $valores, $encontrados);
$total = 0;
foreach ($encontrados[1] as $encontrado) {
    printf ($total += $encontrado);
}`  E veja o valor que ele me retornou das seguinte linhas `12356|743|4584|1|3|03|2016|127.000|
12356|747|9176|1|3|03|2016|1123.511|
12356|748|7559|1|3|03|2016|776.799|
12356|749|1467|1|3|03|2016|601.017|` Resultado= `1271250.5112027.312628.327`

Comment: Já tentei com o que achei na net. Mais nada e relacionado. Notei que ai ele esta somando sim. No resultado que deu `1271250.5112027.312628.327` a soma total ficou no final depois do .31, Sendo 2628.327.

Comment: Desculpe, reescrevi o código e acabei tirando a chamada do `floatval` ali no meio. Tente agora.

Comment: Veja como usei: `$valores = file_get_contents('tce.txt');
preg_match_all('/\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|3\|\d+\|\d+\|(\d+\.\d+)\|/', 
$valores, $encontrados);
$total = 0;
foreach ($encontrados[1] as $encontrado) {
    print $total += floatval($encontrado);
}` e mesmo assim não da certo. E agora me traz esse resultado:  `1271250.5112027.312628.327` será que estou escrevendo certo ali na hora de puxar o arquivo txt?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41466/discussion-between-willian-coqueiro-and-rodrigo-rigotti).

Comment: Pelo bate papo o amigo me ajudou e o final do codigo ficou assim `$valores = file_get_contents('tce.txt'); 
preg_match_all('/\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|3\|\d+\|\d+\|(\d+\.\d+)\|/',  $valores, $encontrados);
$total = 0;
foreach ($encontrados[1] as $encontrado) {
    $total += floatval($encontrado);
}
print $total;`